# Number of Edges and Cycle Detection?

Tags: graph, tree, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, depth-first-search

I ran into a challenging question: When we know the Number of Edges, in `O(|V|)` and not `O(|V|+|E|)`, we can detect whether a simple undirected graph has a cycle or not.

I know there is an `O(|V|)` algorithm for finding out whether a cycle exists or not. But the above sentence says, with knowing number of edges?!! anyone could describe it's true or false?

Answer (score 1):

In an undirected graph, if the graph is connected and there are more edges than are needed to make the graph connected, it contains a cycle. In other words, a graph of V vertices requires V-1 edges to be connected. Any additional edges must connect two vertices that are already in the same component, thereby creating a cycle.

In other words, if the graph contains more than V-1 edges, it contains a cycle.

Comment: if we nothing know about connected  or not connected graph?

Comment: We only know for certain if the graph has more than V-1 edges (and the graph is either connected or disconnected). If it is disconnected and contains less than V-2 edges, it could contain a cycle, but this method won't help.

To summarize, if the graph, whether connected or disconnected, has more than V-1 edges, it contains a cycle. If it is disconnected and contains more than V-2 edges, it contains a cycle. If it contains less than V-2 edges, it **might** contain a cycle.

Comment: so you means with knowing number of edges and count the vertex in O(|V|) and compare it with V-2, then we sure it's has a cycle or not? (any simple undirected graph) ?

Comment: What do you mean by "count the vertex in O(|V|)"? Knowing nothing about connectivity, any simple undirected graph must contain a cycle if it contains more than **V-1** edges.

To justify this, consider a set of V points. The MST that connects all of these V points has V-1 edges. If you add another edge, you are connecting two vertices that are already in the same component, thereby creating a cycle.

Comment: so you means my first sentence in above question is TRUE?

Comment: Not exactly. You have to compare it with V-1 to be sure. In other words, if E > V - 1, there exists a cycle. The inverse is not necessarily true, though.

Comment: why not exactly?, I means when we know the Number of Edges, in O(|V|)we can detect whether a simple undirected Graph has a cycle just by enumerate the vertex and compare it with E > V-1 ? am I right?

Comment: The method I provided was a method to determine (only positively, not negatively) if the graph contains a cycle in O(1) time given the number of vertices and edges. It only applies if E > V - 1. In the case this is not true, nothing can be said about the graph using this method. Are you saying that the runtime of the algorithm is allowed to be O(|V|)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70767/discussion-between-maryam-ghizh-and-colavitam).

Comment: Oh, I apologize. I misunderstood your question. Given that information, you can simply perform a DFS of the graph (note that this requires O(V) memory). If, during the DFS, you reach a vertex that has already been visited (except by returning on the path by which you reached that vertex), then the graph contains a cycle. Given the constraint discussed earlier, this necessarily takes O(V) time.

Comment: my question is why questioner say, " when we know the Number of Edges" ?